# Spring boot AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I'm trying to create a dynamic data source (session based) using AbstractRoutingDataSource but spring boot keeps on calling the determineCurrentLookupKey() function of the AbstractRoutingDataSource  at startup.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.int")
@Bean
public DataSource internal() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.ext")
@Bean
public DataSource external() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@Qualifier("dataSource")
public DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver dataSource() {
    DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver resolver = new DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver();
    DataSource internal = internal();
    DataSource external = external();
    Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
    dataSources.put(env.getRequiredProperty("app.param.int"), internal);
    dataSources.put(env.getRequiredProperty("app.param.ext"), external);
    resolver.setDefaultTargetDataSource(internal);
    resolver.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
    resolver.afterPropertiesSet();

    return resolver;
}

public class DynamicRoutingDataSourceResolver extends  AbstractRoutingDataSource {

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)  RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    Object o = request.getSession().getAttribute(Constant.DATASOURCE);
    return o;

}
```

}

it throws a NullPointerException because the RequestAttributes is null.
I tried to put @Primary into one of the datasource but the AbstractRoutingDataSource determineCurrentLookupKey()  is not being triggered when I try to execute a query.

I'm using spring data jpa.

see also [session based data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610353/spring-boot-with-session-based-data-source/40016380)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to specify any form of `@Primary` here.

Simply create and assign all your data sources to `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.  If there is  one data source that is to be the default, also set it using `#setDefaultTargetDataSource` just like your code shows.

The `NullPointerException` in your case is simply something your code needs to guard against.  If you find that your request data isn't present in your resolver, simply return a `null` value for the data source lookup key.

`AbstractRoutingDataSource` uses the default data source defined if the lookup key returned is either `null` or the specified key was not defined a data source through the lookup map.