# How to open connection at run time in spring boot jpa?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a blocking in opening a connection to database at run time in Spring boot JPA.
Example:
I use SQL Server. My database generate every day with database name pattern: DBDaily
DBDaily01012020
DBDaily01022020
DBDaily01032020
DBDaily01042020
...
I write a Spring Boot console application to export data from these database base on date by user input. Could you please help to open connection to these database to get data ?

Comment: Having a database for every day seems like a big design flaw. A single database, with objects with a date column would seem *far* more appropriate.

Comment: That's right @Lamu. This is old system i can not change it

Comment: A system being old isn't an excuse to not change it. Often it's more of a reason to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataSource bean programatically in your application. There you can generate the url by appending the database name as per specific format. Implement the method `getMyDbName()` to return database name as per the naming convention. Also, you need to add a logic to refresh this config everyday as per the schedule. Or configure session based datasource. Refer [Spring Boot with session-based data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610353/spring-boot-with-session-based-data-source/28626486#28626486)

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.com:1433;DatabaseName=" + getMyDbName());
        dataSourceBuilder.username("AAAA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("AAAA");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Satish, I will try to apply your solution.